# Does there exist a 'single' SQL query for getting unique counts by column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

TABLE

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
a    1    Z
a    2    Z
a    null empty
b    1    Z
b    2    X
b    3    Y
b    3    Y
```

I want to know the count of distinct values by column.

- Col1 count = 2
- Col2 count = 3 (or 4 uncertain null handling)
- Col3 count = 3 (or 4 uncertain empty handling)

I have been attempting different counting and grouping clauses, but this may be not the way.

Comment: This would look like `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1), COUNT(DISTINCT col2), COUNT(DISTINCT col3) FROM yourtable`

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Appreciate the syntax given in comment and answer.

Comment: What about it is not a duplicate? The accepted answer is the same as the duplicate answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count(distinct ...)` should do the trick

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Col1] varchar(50),[Col2] int,[Col3] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('a',1,'Z')
,('a',2,'Z')
,('a',null,'')  -- Note the empty string
,('b',1,'Z')
,('b',2,'X')
,('b',3,'Y')
,('b',3,'Y')
 
Select Col1 = count(distinct col1)
      ,Col2 = count(distinct col2)
      ,Col3 = count(distinct nullif(col3,''))  -- Remove NullIf() if you want to count empty strings
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
2     3     3
```

Comment: `count(distinct nullif(col3,''))` is going to be a little inefficient as it cannot use indexes. Might be better to do `count(distinct col3) - iif(count(case when col3 = '' then 1 end) > 0, -1, 0)`

Comment: @Charlieface. Just illustrating a method to exclude empty strings.   Personally, an empty string is a value.   I also I would have to benchmark your suggestions to be convinced